# React Native game, MongoDB or Firestore

Tags: mongodb, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a  multiplayer react native game for android, it's just a text game.
For now, I've been working only on the client side but I'm slowly getting to the point where I need to choose a way to manage data. Since I'm always trying to learn something new - first time using RN too -, I came across Firestore and I'm curious if it's a viable choice from my project.

For example, in this game you can buy/open companies. If I were to handle this action in nodejs + MongoDB I'd send a JWT token to `server/api/newcompany`.

Assuming I'd have 2 MongoDB models, `Users` with all the user info and `Company` a list of all Companies in game. First I'd check if the User had enough money to open the company and then return some message based on that, my code would be something like this:

```
// routes.js
...
router.post('/api/newcompany',AuthCheck, Company.new)


// controllers/company.js
...
new: async function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body.companyType || !validCompanyType) {
        return res.status(200).send('invalid/missing message and other failed checks')
    }
    //assuming token data would be passed from auth middleware and would have company prices somewhere
    const user =  await Users.find({id:token.userId})
    if (user.money < companyPrice) {
        res.status(200).send('no money')
    } else {
        const newCompany = new Company()
        newCompany.name = req.body.name
        ...
        new.Companny.save(function(){
            res.status(200).send('all good')
        })

    }
}
```

Looking at Firestore I'd have the same 2 documents as above. `Users` with a list of sub-documents(the users) identified by their IDs and a document `Companies`.

Would I be able to do the same users checks as above? 
How would I handle that? Would I use the Firestore Rules to check the user has enough money or would I use my server with admin SDK as an intermediary to handle more complex ops and use the direct Firestore connection just for retrieving data?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you checked out cloud functions? Seems like it could handle a lot of your possible needs for the game.

Comment: From what I've read so far it seems cloud functions are for reacting to actions not handling them. Send a mail after a new user is added to the DB or create a user when someone Authenticats for the first time and other things like that.

Comment: While listeners are a large part of cloud functions, there are games that are currently using them to handle complex actions. If you want to avoid that route though, going with the admin sdk/firestore data connection is probably the most straightforward approach.

Comment: Seems my research didn't take me that far. Seems it's possible to handle https requests with cloud functions. Thanks.